# Can I let my LDAP search fail when group in filter doesn't exist?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

My .Net 4.5 C# application queries an MS AD server via LDAP using DirectoryServices.Protocols. One of the queries needs to find all users for a given AD group, using an *externally provided* filter string like this:

```
(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(memberof=CN=Gorillas,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=local))
```

When the given usergroup does not exist at all in the AD tree, I want the query to fail. Currently it just returns 0 results.

Is there a way to modify the query or filter, or add LDAP controls to let the AD server fail this query when the group doesn't exist?

One alternative I can think of is parsing the provided filter string and getting all referenced 'memberof' groups, and doing separate queries to the AD server to verify their existence, but I'd rather let the server do the filter parsing to prevent mistakes.

Comment: No, you cannot change the semantics of LDAP to suit yourself. They are already defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get an error back from LDAP, if the search is successful but returns no result. The only case you can get an error for a search filter, is when the filter is invalid.